# Error: Manifest file '$(component)\manifest.yml' not found

Tags: python, azure-devops

I have my `manifest.yml` file in a path assets/ccm-lv,I am running a python script `relmgr.py` by passing arguments(path to manifest.yml) as parameters from `azure-pipelines.yml` but the script returns `manifest.yml` not found

`Error: Manifest file '$(component)\manifest.yml' not found`.

[image: repo contents]

the Python script should accept the following command-line arguments: `--newrel <a semver string>` and `--component <path to the directory of manifest.yml>`, and create the current Hybrid-M release structure mentioned in the script

I have passed parameters here to the azure pipelines

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  How exactly are you running the command?  What is $(component)?

Comment: 1. How did you define the parameter "Component Directory"? Is "Component Directory" the display name of parameter `component`? Or is `component` a variable? 2. What's the actual value of `--component <path to the directory of manifest.yml>`? 3. It would be better if you can share your pipeline's YAML file, so that we can get a clearer picture of your pipeline and share possible suggestions. (Remove personal info from the YAML)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I figured out that the component path had to be $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\path_to_manifest.yml

I gave it and was able to resolve the issue

Thank you

Comment: Thanks for sharing the root cause and solution. `Build.SourcesDirectory` is the local path on the agent where your source code files are downloaded. You need to specify the relative path of the target file based on the local path. You can copy the relative path directly from the repo. To help others who have the similar issue, it's suggested that you share your solution as an answer below.